# Line drawing drawn inverted in OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to draw a simple line drawing connecting several vertices in OpenGL ES. However, the line is drawn inverted or in a different position from where it should be drawn. I've attached the class for the line drawing below

```
ConnectingPath.java 
--------------------

public class ConnectingPath {

int positionBufferId;

PointF[] verticesList;
public float vertices[];
public FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;

public ConnectingPath(LinkedList<PointF> verticesList, float[] colors)
{
    List<PointF> tempCorners = verticesList;

    int i = 0;
    this.verticesList = new PointF[tempCorners.size()];
    for (PointF corner : tempCorners) {
        this.verticesList[i++] = corner;
    }

}

public float[] getTransformedVertices()
{
    float z;
    List<Float> finalVertices = new ArrayList<Float>();

    finalVertices.clear();
    for(PointF point : verticesList){
        finalVertices.add(point.x);
        finalVertices.add(point.y);
        finalVertices.add(0.0f);
    }

    int i = 0;
    float[] verticesArray = new float[finalVertices.size()];
    for (Float f : finalVertices) {
        verticesArray[i++] = (f != null ? f : Float.NaN);
    }
    return verticesArray;
}

public void initBooth(){
    vertices = this.getTransformedVertices();

    for(Float f : vertices){
        Log.d("Mapsv3--", f + "");
    }

    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    int[] buffers = new int[1];
    GLES11.glGenBuffers(1, buffers, 0);
    GLES11.glBindBuffer(GLES11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
    GLES11.glBufferData(GLES11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * vertices.length, vertexBuffer, GLES11.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    positionBufferId = buffers[0];
}

public void Render(GL10 gl){
    GLES11.glPushMatrix();
    GLES11.glBindBuffer(GLES11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferId);
    GLES11.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    GLES11.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
    GLES11.glBindBuffer(GLES11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GLES11.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);
    GLES11.glLineWidth(10.0f);
    GLES11.glColor4f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    GLES11.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, verticesList.length);
    GLES11.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    GLES11.glPopMatrix();
  }
}
```

Drawing code :

```
Renderer.java
--------------

// Variables here


public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    viewWidth = width;
    viewHeight = height;
}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);            //Enable Texture Mapping
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);            //Enable Smooth Shading
    gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);    //Grey Background
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);                     //Depth Buffer Setup
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);            //Enables Depth Testing
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);             
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, -viewWidth/2, viewWidth/2, -viewHeight/2,viewHeight/2);
    gl.glTranslatef(center.x,center.y,0);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glTranslatef(0,0, 0);
    gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_FRONT);

    if(connectingPath!=null){
        connectingPath.Render(gl);
    }

    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
 }
```

Screenshot :

[image: Screenshot of the Path drawn inverted]

Comment: Have you tried negating Y-values?

Comment: No..but that would be drawing it the wrong way right?

Comment: Where do you assume the origin (0,0) to be? In OpenGL, it is the bottom left corner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drawing in OpenGL seems to be inverted for you due to the way OpenGL defines it's screen coordinates. In contrast to most 2D drawing API's, the origin is located in the bottom left corner, which means that the y axis values increase when moving upwards. A very nice explanation is available in the [OpenGL common pitfalls (Number 12)](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/features/KilgardTechniques/oglpitfall/):

> Given a sheet of paper, people write from the top of the page to the bottom. The origin for writing text is at the upper left-hand margin of the page (at least in European languages). However, if you were to ask any decent math student to plot a few points on an X-Y graph, the origin would certainly be at the lower left-hand corner of the graph. Most 2D rendering APIs mimic writers and use a 2D coordinate system where the origin is in the upper left-hand corner of the screen or window (at least by default). On the other hand, 3D rendering APIs adopt the mathematically minded convention and assume a lower left-hand origin for their 3D coordinate systems.